# how to import from oracle?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, sql-loader

friends I've tried to import data from oracle using command line by following command:

```
expdp hr/Password1 DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=hr.dump
```

i got the dump file but problem is it is not in readable form!and also i've  try to export to another schema using

```
C:\Users\thiyagarajan_a>impdp schema1/Password1 DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=scott.
dmp
```

data didn't get exported!

can anyone explain me what is exactly going on here!

Comment: you want to inport or export as you have mention expdp command

Comment: ya first i want to import data from one database and then export it to another db!

Comment: then you create to export first then import into another as i have mention command.

Comment: _but problem is it is not in readable form!_ - the dump files are meant to be binary & aren't readable in text editors.

Answer (score 0):

Table Exports/Imports:

The TABLES parameter is used to specify the tables that are to be exported. The following is an example of the table export and import syntax.

```
expdp scott/tiger@db10g tables=EMP,DEPT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=expdpEMP_DEPT.log

impdp scott/tiger@db10g tables=EMP,DEPT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=impdpEMP_DEPT.log
```

For Schema Exports/Imports :

The OWNER parameter of exp has been replaced by the SCHEMAS parameter which is used to specify the schemas to be exported. The following is an example of the schema export and import syntax.

```
expdp scott/tiger@db10g schemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=expdpSCOTT.log

impdp scott/tiger@db10g schemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=impdpSCOTT.log
```

Comment: dude,is dump file can open in notepad!?

Comment: The log file will have the entire content listing of the .dmp file  You can open the log file using NOTEPAD.

Comment: dude when i try to import the dump file which i get by the above method I've got the error as:ORA-39000: bad dump file specification

Comment: C:\Users\thiyagarajan_a>exp file= sql_loader_dump.dmp log=name.log tables='schem
a1.test_sqlldr' feedback=10000 buffer=3000000

Comment: above the command which i used to export file from my database!by using this command i've got a dump file under the name as 'loader_dump.dmp'..after that i used to import this in to another table for than i used:C:\Users\thiyagarajan_a>impdp schema1/Password1 tables=new_sqlldr_1 directory=at
r dumpfile=C:\Users\thiyagarajan_a/sql_loader_dump.dmp logfile=C:\Users\thiyagar
ajan_a/NEW_SQLLDR_2316_5128.log

Comment: when i run the above import command I've got the following error:Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Produc
tion
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39088: file name cannot contain a path specification

Comment: there will be file in your command or instead of file ,dumpfile should come

Comment: your dump file name is differ u have used in impdb sql_loader_dump.dmp.but you have export into loader_dump.dmp'

Comment: ah...dude i got the desired  result!friend...wat i did the mistake is for exporting i've used exp but import for import impdp this cause the damn error!

Comment: dude,actually i'v create one directory using sql *plus using create directory <name> as <path>; after execute this command i didn't see this directory in that specific path